# Jest issue. FakeTimers: clearTimeout was invoked to clear a native timer instead of one created by this library

Tags: node.js, jestjs, bitbucket-pipelines, cicd

After the update of Node.js from version 14 to version 16, we've got a lot of failed tests on bitbucket CI/CD pipelines. Locally tests pass.

Seems like the problem in timers, cause the first error message says: "FakeTimers: clearTimeout was invoked to clear a native timer instead of one created by this library.
To automatically clean-up native timers, use `shouldClearNativeTimers`". After that, a bunch of test fails.

After adding "--runInBand" parameter for jest it solves the issue, but it's not an ideal approach.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: This warning comes from the sinonjs/fake-timers package.  There does't appear to be a way to provide configuration directly to the fake timer in Jest.  I was able to supress this warning by modifying the config passed to sinon in my node_modules.  https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers#var-clock--faketimersinstallconfig

See: https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/66408c35dc22b4259d3e27c504921198ff143115/packages/jest-fake-timers/src/modernFakeTimers.ts#L102-L106

Answer (score 6):

i had this same issue.

Adding

```
jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()
jest.useRealTimers()
```

in the end of my test that had the useFakeTimers() fixed it.

reference: https://testing-library.com/docs/using-fake-timers/

Comment: I had an open handle in `Jest` that started happening after I introduced `jest.useFakeTimers().setSystemTime(new Date("this is not a date: is just a random date in the future"))` and putting this at the end of the test suite solved the open handle! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @dagadm did not work for me. It turns out I was using jest 26 which was the problem. The following fixed it for me.

```
npm i --save-dev jest@27 ts-jest@27 @types/jest@27
```

Then, of course, I ran into the "Test functions cannot both take a 'done' callback" issue which is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70884240/test-functions-cannot-both-take-a-done-callback). I had to remove all my `done` functions from async tests.