# Cannot get a recursive async function to work without 'done' in jest unit test

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am having a similar issue to [Test functions cannot both take a 'done' callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70884240/test-functions-cannot-both-take-a-done-callback), but none of the solutions are working or applicable to me: I have a test file which needs to run `done()` in order to setup an async test, but am getting the error:

> Test functions cannot both take a 'done' callback and return something. Either use a 'done' callback, or return a promise.
>
> Returned value: Promise {}

Because I am using jest v28.1.3.

In order to setup my environment, I run a recursive async function which looks like the following:

```js
const iAmReady = async (done) => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    try {
      await request.get({ uri: 'http://localhost:7575/ready' })
      done()
    } catch (err) {
      attempts += 1
      if (attempts > 10) {
        throw new Error('Failed to connect.')
      }
      iAmReady(done)
    }
  }, 500)
}
```

I then set this function to run in the `beforeAll`:

```js
  beforeAll(async (done) => {
    await iAmReady(done)
  })

  it('test', () => {
    // test stuff
  })
```

Unfortunately when I pass in the done as shown here, although it works an my environment is set up I get the error I stated above.

If I don't pass in the done and remove its usage from `iAmReady`, the setup is ignored and done only after the tests run.

What can I do to replace the `done` and make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `request`lib returns a promise? I think it accepts a callback instead.

And the reason jest is complaining is that you use `done` and `async` flag at the same time. If you return the promise then do not use `done`. When it has `async` flags it's already a promise.

This code should work for you with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

```js
function ready(attempts = 0) {
  return axios
    .get('http://localhost:3000/api/health')
    .then(() => 'ok')
    .catch(() => {
      if (attempts > 10) return Promise.reject('failed to connect');
      const delay = attempts * 10;
      console.log(`Waiting ${delay}ms...`);
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(ready(attempts + 1)), delay));
    });
}

beforeAll(() => ready()); // Since it returns a promise no need async flag
```

p.s.

If you are using built-in `http.request` this is how to make it promise-based.  [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533580/nodejs-how-to-promisify-http-request-reject-got-called-two-times)